# Powershell Message Event Log Search FilterHashTable

Tags: filter, hash

I am using powershell to sift through my event log in event viewer. The challenge is to locate specific character sets inside the message detail and to display both the events with those character sets and the individual character sets themselves. 
Right now, I have the following:

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Application"; id=1035} -MaxEvents 10 | where {$_.message -like "* Visual C++ *" }

This script will return the events that have messages with Visual C++ inside, however there is a set of about 7 characters after that ranging in letter and number. I need to extract those 7 characters and print them exclusively. Thank you for all help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be Craft related.

Comment: This is definitely not Craft related. Migrating to SO.